# Third coefficient of the chromatic polynomial

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

If G is a graph and $\chi(G,k)=\sum _{i=0} ^{n-1}  a_i k^{n-i}$

I know that $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = -|E(G)|$

I'm looking for a formula for $a_2$ using |V|, |E| and the number of independent sets of size 3 in G.

I already know that $a_2 = {|E| \choose 2} - T$ when T is the number of triangles in G, but I didn't understand the proof for that, and it's not something we learned in class nor I don't know how to go from this to what I'm looking for. I do see some resemblance (number of triangles and number of independent sets of size 3), but that is as much as I see...

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are you looking for ? A proof of the stated identity for $a_2$?

Comment: a formula for $a_2$ using |V|, |E| and the number of independent sets of size 3 in G

Comment: given that you know $a_2$ depdens on the number of triangles, your task is then to express $t$ in terms of $|V|,|E|$ and the number of independent sets of size $3$. I am not sure that's doable without also knowing the number of $2$-paths.

Comment: I know that $a_2$ depends on the number of triangles, but I know that from an Internet research, not from knowledge I got from class, and I can't use that (well, I can, but I'll need to justify that too).

Comment: You could use induction on $|V|, |E|$, using the fact that $\chi (k; G) = \chi (k; G - uv) - \chi (k; G \circ uv)$, where $G \circ uv$ is the contraction of edge $uv$. You already know $a_1 = -|E|$, and you need to also use the fact that triangles containing $uv$ are contracted to single edges in $G \circ uv$. (A trivial fact you probably know is $\deg (\chi (k; G)) = |V|$.)

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4291161/coefficient-of-chromatic-polynomial

Answer (score 1):

**Whitney Polynomial's Recursion:**
Let $G$ be a graph  Let $\chi(G;k)$ denote the chromatic polynomial of the graph. As RandomStudent correctly pointed out in the comments, that using the fact that $\chi(G;k) = \chi(G-uv;k) - \chi(G.uv;k)$ where $G.uv$ is the contraction of edge $uv$.

**Solution**
We first assume we have this formula for the chromatic polynomial of a graph. Number of vertices in $G-uv$ is still $|V|$ while that in $G.uv$ is $|V-1|$.

Applying Induction on the number of edges.
(I will leave the step of proving the base case as an exercise for you)
Assuming it to be true for $|E|$ edges. Since both $G-uv$ & $G.uv$ have $|E-1|$ edges so it is true for them. Now $a_1$ is the coefficient for $x^{n-2}$ for $G.uv$ while $a_2$ is the coefficient for $x^{n-1}$ for $G-uv$. $a_1$ for $G.uv$ is $|E-1|$ So we get applying induction we get $\binom{E}{2} - T = \binom{E-1}{2} - T + (E-1)$.

**Alternative:**
There exists another solution by a completely different method to a very similar question here

[Formula for coefficient of $x^{n-2}$ in the chromatic polynomial of a graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4291161/formula-for-coefficient-of-xn-2-in-the-chromatic-polynomial-of-a-graph?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: It looks correct, it has been years since I learned graph theory, so I'm not sure. I'll try to go over this proof later

Comment: I realized that this was quite an old question but I didn't find this solution anyone so thought of writing it over here.