# Finding a Graph given a chromatic polynomial

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

> Let $f(k) = k^6 - 6k^5 + 15k^4 - 17k^3 + 7k^2$. Show carefully that there is only one simple graph with chromatic polynomial equal to $f(k)$, and find that graph. Verify that the graph you found does indeed have chromatic polynomial equal to $f(k)$.

I have no idea how to go about finding a specific graph given a chromatic polynomial. Despite extensive searching I haven't been able to find any help on this topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at the things we can figure out easily:

1. The graph has $6$ vertices, because the polynomial has degree $6$. (In general, the chromatic polynomial of an $n$-vertex graph is somewhere between $k^n$ and $k(k-1)(\dotsb)(k-n+1)$.)
2. The graph is bipartite, because $f(2) = 4$ is nonzero.
3. When $2$-coloring a bipartite graph, once you color a single vertex, the coloring of its connected component is forced. So the graph must have $2$ connected components, because there are $2^2 = 4$ $2$-colorings.

From here, you only have a few possibilities. Brute force is not out of the question. (And you don't have to try every possibility for brute force to work: if you try a graph $G$ and it has too few colorings, then you know that adding edges to $G$ can't help. Same with removing edges from a graph with too many colorings.) But there are still more things you can figure out from other values of $f$.

For example: when you $3$-color a graph with two connected components, you expect a factor of $3!$ from each component (by permuting the colors used on it). But $f(3) = 90$ is not divisible by $3!^2 = 36$. What does that tell you about the components?

Comment: Some other useful facts: the chromatic polynomial of a graph is the product of the chromatic polynomials of its connected components, so if you can factor the chromatic polynomial, you get some more useful information. The coefficient of the next-to-leading term is the negative of the number of edges. The coefficient of the third-highest power relates to the number of triangles, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636062/third-coefficient-of-the-chromatic-polynomial

Comment: Why is degree of chromatic polynomial of a n-vertex graph, n?

Comment: @mathnoob Because the upper and lower bounds on the chromatic polynomial (which I gave in my answer, and which come from the empty graph and the complete graph respectively) are both degree $n$. If the chromatic polynomial of an $n$-vertex graph did not have degree $n$, then it would not stay between those bounds for large $k$.

Comment: Or to put it differently: for extremely large $k$, the number of ways to $k$-color an $n$-vertex graph should be about $k^n$, because we have $n$ choices with about $k$ options for each.

Comment: If you have the contraction-deletion formula, the degree is easy to see. Every deletion brings you closer to the graph on $n$ vertices with no edges, with polynomial $k^n$, and every contraction reduces the number of vertices, so (by induction) contributes a term of lower degree.

Comment: @GerryMyerson There's also the formula as a sum over partitions into independent sets: one partition is always the one into $n$ singletons, which contributes a degree $n$ term, and the rest contribute lower-order terms.