# Coefficient of $x^{n-2}$ in the chromatic polynomial of a graph

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, graph-theory, coloring

Define the chromatic polynomial of a graph $G$ as the number of its (proper) vertex $k$-colorings. In other words, it is the unique polynomial $P(G,x)$ which, evaluated at any integer $k\geq 0 $, coincides with $P(G,k)$.

Here are some well-known facts about its coefficients (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial#Properties)):

- The coefficients of $x^0,\dots,x^c$ are zeros, where $c$ denotes the number of connected components of $G$.
- The coefficients of $x^c, \dots,x^n$ are all non-zero and alternate in signs.
- The coefficient of $x^n$ is $1$ (the polynomial is monic).
- The coefficient of $x^{n−1}$ is $-e$, where $e$ is the number of edges in the graph $G$.

I got curious about the coefficient of $x^{n-2}$. After some experimenting, I found the following formula that seems to hold for all graphs I investigated so far:
$$a^{n-2} = \frac{1}{2}e(e-1) - t \, ,$$
where $e$ is the number of edges, and $t$ is the number of triangles in the graph $G$.

My question now is: Is this a known formula? If yes, is there some intuition behind why this should be true?

Comment: It is a known result, see, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4291161/coefficient-of-chromatic-polynomial