# Extracting girth from the chromatic polynomial

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

**Context.** Given a (simple) graph $G$, the *chromatic polynomial* $p(k)$ of $G$ counts the number of proper $k$-colorings of the graph $G$. We know that $p(k)$ encodes a lot of information about the graph $G$. For example, we can read the number of connected components by looking at the lowest exponent of $k$ in the expansion of $p(k)$. We can also read the number of edges by looking at the coefficient of $k^{n-1}$, and the number of triangles in $G$ by looking at the coefficient of $k^{n-2}$. There are more advanced results (for example, Whitney's broken-circuit theorem) which give a combinatorial interpretation for each coefficient of $p(k)$.

**Definition.** Recall that the *girth* of a graph $G$ is the length of the shortest cycle in $G$.

**Question.** I remember seeing in some paper (whose title I forgot) that the girth of the graph can be recovered from its chromatic polynomial. Is this actually true? If so, how can we prove it?

Reference to the literature which contains this result (with proof) would be much appreciated, but I am also happy with a self-contained proof. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original citation for this claim appears to be:

> Xu, S. J. "A lemma in studying chromaticity." Ars Combinatoria 32 (1991): 315-318.

At the time, Ars Combinatoria only published in print, I couldn't find a scanned copy online, and I'm too lazy to go to the library. But we are now armed with the knowledge that there *is* a proof. Also, we know from papers citing this one that more is true: from the chromatic polynomial, we know the *number* of cycles of the smallest possible length. Having all that at our disposal, how could we *not* prove this theorem?

**Theorem.** Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices, $m$ edges, girth $g$, and $k$ cycles of length $g$. Then the chromatic polynomial of $G$ has the form
$$
    x^n - m x^{n-1} + \binom m2 x^{n-2} - \binom m3 x^{n-3} + \dots + (-1)^{g-1} \left(\binom m{g-1} - k\right) x^{n-g+1} + \dots
$$
That is, the coefficient of $x^{n-i}$ for $0\le i<g-1$ is $(-1)^i \binom mi$, and the coefficient of $x^{n-g+1}$ is $(-1)^{g-1}\left(\binom m{g-1}-k\right)$.

**Proof.** We induct on the number of edges in $G$ using deletion-contraction. There are two cases we'll deal with separately, which will be our base cases. First, the $g=3$ case, which is proved, for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4291161). (The nice thing about skipping the $g=3$ case and going to triangle-free graphs is that now, edge contraction is guaranteed to reduce the number of edges by exactly $1$.) Second, the case of forests, which have infinite girth. A forest has chromatic polynomial $x^{n-m}(x-1)^m$, in which the coefficient of $x^{n-i}$ is $(-1)^i \binom{m}{i}$ for all $i$, so it can also be said to satisfy this theorem - and will work fine for our induction.

Now assume that $G$ has girth $3 < g < \infty$ (so it does contain cycles, and they're not triangles). Let $e$ be an edge which lies on $t>0$ of the cycles of length $g$. Then:

- Deleting $e$ yields a graph $G-e$ with $n$ vertices and $m-1$ edges, which either has girth $g$ and $k-t$ cycles of length $g$, or (if $k=t$) girth greater than $g$. In either case, its chromatic polynomial begins $$x^n - (m-1)x^{n-1} + \binom{m-1}{2} x^{n-2} + \dots + (-1)^{g-1}\left(\binom{m-1}{g-1} - (k-t)\right)x^{n-g+1}.$$
- Contracting $e$ yields a graph $G \bullet e$ with $n-1$ vertices and $m-1$ edges, which has girth $g-1$ and $t$ cycles of length $g-1$. (Its only cycles of length $g-1$ are formed by cycles of length $g$ in $G$ which used edge $e$.) Its chromatic polynomial begins $$x^{n-1} - (m-1)x^{n-2} + \binom{m-1}{2} x^{n-3} + \dots + (-1)^{g-2} \left(\binom{m-1}{g-2} - t\right)x^{n-g+1}.$$

The chromatic polynomial of $G$ is obtained by subtracting the chromatic polynomial of $G\bullet e$ from the chromatic polynomial of $G-e$. In the first few coefficients, that yields a term $$(-1)^i \left(\binom{m-1}{i} + \binom{m-1}{i-1}\right)x^{n-i}$$ which simplifies to $(-1)^i \binom mi x^{n-i}$, as intended. The coefficient of $x^{n-g+1}$ is a slightly more complicated story: here, we see $$(-1)^{g-1}\left(\binom{m-1}{g-1} - (k-t)\right)x^{n-g+1} -  (-1)^{g-2} \left(\binom{m-1}{g-2} - t\right)x^{n-g+1}$$ Here, the binomial coefficients also combine into the $\binom{m}{g-1}$ we wanted, while $-(k-t) - t$ simplifies to $-k$. So the theorem holds for $G$ as well; by induction, it holds for all graphs.

---

Actually, this can also be proven from Whitney's broken-circuit theorem, which is mentioned in the question. Write the chromatic polynomial of $G$ as $$\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i a_i(G) x^{n-i}.$$ If we fix an arbitrary ordering of the edges of $G$, then a *broken circuit* of $G$ is a path obtained by deleting the maximum edge from a cycle of $G$. Whitney's broken-circuit theorem states that $a_i(G)$ is equal to the number of $i$-element subsets of $E(G)$ which do not contain any broken circuit as a subset. In particular:

- If $G$ has girth $g$, then every broken circuit contains at least $g-1$ edges, and so $a_i(G) = \binom mi$ for all $i<g-1$.
- If there are $k$ cycles of length $g$, then there are $k$ broken circuits of size $g-1$, which are the only $(g-1)$-element subsets of $E(G)$ containing a broken circuit. Therefore $a_{g-1}(G) = \binom m{g-1} - k$.

This proves the theorem above, and tells us that from the chromatic polynomial, we can first recover $g$ (as the least integer for which $a_{g-1}(G) < \binom m{g-1}$) and then $k$ (as $\binom{m}{g-1} - a_{g-1}(G)$).

Comment: Thank you so much, Misha! This was a highly instructive answer.